# Http Get Request com Axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Preciso de ajuda para fazer um `get` para minha **restAPI** passando parametro *(Não sei se é assim que se chama, se puder falar como é que se diz, eu agradeço!).*

O que eu faço é chamar uma lista em *http://localhost:6000/API/Lojas*

```
  axios.get(' http://localhost:6000/API/Lojas ').then(response => {
              this.data = response.data.Data
           })
```

Eu preciso fazer 2 checkbox com valores para fazer um get nesta URL: 

*http://localhost:6000/API/Lojas**?deletado=true***
ou
*http://localhost:6000/API/Lojas**?deletado=false***

Como eu posso fazer isso? Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é simples, basta você declarar assim

```
<script>
   export default{
      data(){
          return{
             checkbox: []
          }
      },
      methods: {
         api(){
            axios.get('http://localhost:6000/API/Lojas', {
                params: {
                   deletado: this.checkbox
                   // Se for falso sera http://localhost:6000/API/Lojas?deletado=false

                   // Se for true será http://localhost:6000/API/Lojas?deletado=true
                }
            })
            .then(response => {
               console.log(response)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                 console.log(error)
            })
         }
      }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Acreditei que fosse simples, é que eu não sabia se era parâmetros mesmo e o google não estava me ajudando rsrs. Se eu quiser passar mais parametros, eu posso adicionar mais elementos para essa propriedade `params` ?

Comment: sim, basta colocar virgula `deletado: this.checkbox, outroParams: this.param` e etc

Comment: Perfeito cara, muito obrigado! :)